# How can I force client to not cache the svelte/rollup bundle.js?

Tags: browser-cache, svelte, rollupjs

My svelte rollup.js setup has an index.html file with this head:

```
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/bundle.css'><!-- svelte -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/index.css" /><!-- tailwind -->
    <script defer src='/build/bundle.js'></script>
```

When I deploy a new version to my web server, some clients don't fetch the new bundle.js but instead use their cached copy. What's a good way of forcing them to fetch the new bundle when I've deployed a new version?

The simplest way I can think of would be to add the version number or git commit hash to the end of src, e.g:

```
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/bundle.css?v0.1.4'><!-- svelte -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/index.css?v0.1.4" /><!-- tailwind -->
    <script defer src='/build/bundle.js?v0.1.4'></script>
```

But I assume this is a common problem, so I'd rather ask.

Comment: Using the app version in your bundling filename is a high used practice. You can find other ideas here https://code-boxx.com/force-browsers-reload-javascript-css/

Answer (score 1):

There's a section in the docs about using hash's in the bundle names. https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputentryfilenames

Comment: Thanks. it works for .js files. How can we do this for CSS files? any idea?

Comment: If the main .html page is cached, it still refers to the .js files with the old hashes, which are probably cached as well. In that case you'll still get the old version of the application, or even worse, only parts of it.
And, the issue is not just with the browser. Files may also be cached by gateways between the client and the server. I haven't found a 100% solid solution yet.